# Solving differential equation $x'=\frac{x+2t}{x-t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation:

$$x'=\frac{x+2t}{x-t}$$

with initial value condition: $x(1)=2$

This is what I have so far:

**Substitution:** $u=\frac{x}{t}$

$$\implies u't+u=\frac{2t+tu}{-t+tu}$$

**Separation of variables:**

$$\implies \frac{u'(u-1)}{-u^2+2u+2}=\frac{1}{t}$$

**Integrate both sides:**

$$\implies \int \frac{u'(u-1)}{-u^2+2u+2} dt=\int \frac{1}{t} dt \iff -\frac{1}{2}\ln(-u^2+2u+2)=\ln(t)+C$$

**Solve for "$u$"**:

$$\implies u=1 \pm\sqrt{\frac{-1+3e^{2C}t^2}{e^{2C}t^2}}$$

**Resubstitution: $u=\frac{x}{t}$**

$$\implies x=t \pm t\sqrt{\frac{-1+3e^{2C}t^2}{e^{2C}t^2}}$$

**Solving for "$C$" using $x(1)=2$:**

$$x(1)=2=1\pm 1\sqrt{\frac{-1+3e^{2C}1^2}{e^{2C}1^2}} \implies C=-\frac{\ln(2)}{2}$$

**Substituting "$C$" into the solution:**

$$x=t \pm t\sqrt{\frac{-1+\frac{3}{2}t^2}{\frac{1}{2}t^2}}=t \pm t\sqrt{3t^2-2}$$

**Plugging "$x$" into the differential equation:**

$$1 \pm (\sqrt{3t^2-2}+\frac{6t^2}{\sqrt{3t^2-2}}) \not = \frac{3t \pm t\sqrt{3t^2-2}}{\pm t\sqrt{3t^2-2}}$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Seperation of variables $\frac 1t$ should be a $\frac{1}{t^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is another way to do this. we have $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{x+2t}{x-t}. $$ we can rewrite this as an exact differential in the form $$0=(t-x) dx + (x+2t) dt = f_x\, dx + f_t \, dt  $$  we have $$f_{xt} = f_{tx} =1 $$

we can integrate $$ f_x = t-x \to f = tx-\frac12x^2 + C(t) \to f_t = x + C'=x+2t\to C= t^2  $$ to  therefore the solution is $$tx - \frac12x^2 + t^2 = 1\times 2-2+1= 1. $$

Comment: Looks nice but I am not sure what you did here. I don't think I have learned this yet. What do $f_{xt}$ and $f_{tx}$ mean?

Comment: @Rzeta,   those are partial derivatives. you may have seen this as implicit differentiation. that is, if differentiate implicitly, $tx - \frac12 x^2 + t^2 = 1,$ you will end up with the differential equation you have at the beginning. think of it as reverse engineering.

Comment: This is a very cool solution and I want to understand it. I get that if you differentiate $tx-\frac{1}{2}x^2+t^2=0$ implicitly you get $x+txx'-xx'+2t=0$ which simplifies to $x'=\frac{x+2t}{x-t}$. But I am still not sure how you got to $tx-\frac{1}{2}x^2+t^2=0$ in the first place.  Did you just integrate $(t-x)dx$ and $(x+2t)dt$?

Comment: I re-read your post and it makes sense now. Just ignore my last comment. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Rzeta, you are welcome. you likely will learn all this formally by the title exact differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

it must be $$\frac{u-1}{-u^2+2u+2}du=\frac{dt}{t}$$
we get
$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln|-u^2+2u+2|=\ln|t|+C$$

Comment: So you are saying my integration is incorrect?

Comment: Isn't this exactly what I got?

Comment: no you forgot the absolut value!

Comment: I am not sure how that changes my calculation. Can you show me how this would change my result?